# This keeps happening in R every time I try to load packages

Tags: r, stringi

So, I keep getting this error:
library(tidyverse)

> Warning: package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.1.3 Error:
> package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i,
> c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):  there is no package
> called ‘stringi’

This is not speciic to tidyverse.  I got the exact same error with installR.  What is stringi? I uninstall and re-installed the stringi package and it continues.  I tried devtools, and it continues.

I tried updating R using installR and the error continues. I tried downloading it from cran and it continues.

Any advice?!  This is super annoying.

Comment: As the message suggests, `stringi` is a package.  It is described [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html).

Comment: It looks in you have an earlier version of R installed.  To make the warning go away try updating to the most recent version of R.

Comment: You have a mismatch between your R version and your packages. If you have updated R you need to update/reinstall all your packages.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you need to install the `stringi` package first. Hence, you need to run the following:

```
install.packages( c('stringi', 'tidyverse') )
```

Alternatively, you can try to install the package with its dependencies using the following:

```
install.packages('tidyverse', dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo") # "this installs all the packages needed to run pkgs, their examples, tests and vignettes (if the package author specified them correctly)." per the description for the help file for install.packages()
```

Comment: In my case, the first one worked charmingly!!